# How to enable JDK 20 preview features in vscode settings.json?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I tried with the below settings.json changes:

```json
{
    "java.configuration.runtimes": [
        {
          "name": "JavaSE-20",
          "path": "/Users/rahulraj/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-20.0.1/Contents/Home",
          "default": true,
          "vmargs": [ "--enable-preview" ]
        },
      ],
}
```

But it is still giving an error while trying to run a virtual thread code:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Preview Features not enabled, need to run with --enable-preview
        at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.PreviewFeatures.ensureEnabled(PreviewFeatures.java:49)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.ofVirtual(Thread.java:859)
        at Test.main(Test.java:21)
```

Here is the path to `settings.json`:
`~/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json`

The changes in `settings.json` seems to be correct and JDK path also seems to be correct. So, I'm not really understanding where exactly it is going wrong here.

Here is my `launch.json`:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "Current File",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "${file}"
        },
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "App",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "App",
            "projectName": "VirtualThread_c7b22327",
            "args": ["--enable-preview"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: @user
got it working after changing `args` to `vmArgs` in `launch.json` !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be putting `--enable-preview` in the `vmArgs` field of your launch.json instead of the `args` field. `args` is passed to the program. `vmArgs` is passed to the [VM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine).